# ngspice, malloc: internal error can't allocate -8 bytes

Tags: simulation, spice

I am new to ngspice and trying to simulate my first circuit. I have posted my spice.net and my simulation.cmd below with a picture of my schematic. When I run the simulation I get the error message:

> malloc: internal error can't allocate -8 bytes.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Thanks

```
* gnetlist -g spice-sdb -o spice.net v-monitor.sch
************************************************** *******
* Spice file generated by gnetlist *
* spice-sdb version 4.28.2007 by SDB -- *
* provides advanced spice netlisting capability. *
* Documentation at http://www.brorson.com/gEDA/SPICE/ *
************************************************** *******
*vvvvvvvv Included SPICE model from /home/matt/Documents/gEDA/model/BC108.mod vvvvvvvv
.MODEL BC108 NPN(Is=1.8E-14 Ise=5.0E-14 Nf=.9955 Ne=1.46 Bf=400
+ Br=35.5 Ikf=.14 Ikr=.03 Isc=1.72E-13 Nc=1.27 Nr=1.005
+ Rb=.56 Re=.6 Rc=.25 Vaf=80 Var=12.5
+ Cje=13E-12 Cjc=4E-12 Vjc=.54 Mjc=.33
+ Tf=.64E-9 Tr=50.72E-9)
* ST pid=23 case=TO18

*^^^^^^^^ End of included SPICE model from /home/matt/Documents/gEDA/models/BC108.mod ^^^^^^^^
*
*vvvvvvvv Included SPICE model from /home/matt/Documents/gEDA/models/BC178.mod vvvvvvvv
.model BC178 pnp(IS=3.50E-15 VAF=80.5 BF=330 IKF=0.1018 NE=1.3140
+ ISE=3.816E-16 IKR=0.03 ISC=5.00E-13 NC=1.6 NR=1 BR=5 RC=0.35
+ CJC=8.80E-12
+ FC=0.5 MJC=0.28 VJC=1 CJE=1.00E-11 MJE=0.38 VJE=0.4 TF=7.00E-10
+ ITF=0.6 VTF=3 XTF=11.5 RB=100 IRB=0.0001 RBM=10 RE=0.75
+ TR=2.00E-07)
*

*^^^^^^^^ End of included SPICE model from /home/matt/Documents/gEDA/models/BC178.mod ^^^^^^^^
*
*============== Begin SPICE netlist of main design ============
.INCLUDE /home/matt/Documents/gEDA/Simulation.cmd
Vcc Vcc 0 DC 15V
Rnb 4 3 4K
Rpb 2 5 22K
Q2 1 5 Vcc BC178
Vpulse 4 0 pulse 0 5 1m 1u 1u 1m 3m
Q1 2 3 0 BC108
R2 0 Vout 1K
R1 Vout 1 2K
.end

P
* .AC DEC 20 1Hz 100MegHz
.DC Vpulse 0 5 .01
* .DC VINPUT 1 2 .01
.plot dc v(Vout) v(Vin)
.print dc v(Vout) v(Vin)
```

[image: Transistor Switch]

Comment: This would appear to be a bug in that version of SPICE. Is there an updated package? Alternatively the latest version from geda may be newer than your distribution's version.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your help. I am trying to reinstall but getting a c-compiler error. Trying to work out how to fix it will let you know the outcome.

Answer (score 2):

You have a line with a single 'P' and nothing else in
  your circuit description.
This line is responsible for the ngspice crash.
You will have to search why your geda frontend
  has generated this line.

Of course ngspice should have emited a reasonable
   error message instead of crashing.
Thus you might consider filing a bug report on the
   ngpsice bug tracker too.

Comment: I have removed the P and there was no difference, still the same error.

Comment: I have retried the experiment. If I remove the 'P' line, then the malloc error disappears. Furthermore I've tracked down the issue to the src/spicelib/parser/inp2p.c file, which is responsible for parsing 'P' lines (aka cplline, coupled lines model). This code fails when searching for the device nodes (you have none,  num = (num - 2) / 2 will evaluate to -1, TMALLOC will try to allocate -1 * sizeof(char*) ...). So please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Malloc = memory allocation and is a software library construct.  Your pspice deck should not be able to evoke this, even though you have an error (or not).  However, this may also come from the compiled model files. You may not be able to fix this yourself and the author may take some time to isolate it and fix it, so you would be well server to reformat your spice netlist to isolate the problem.  In doing so you help the author (if you tell them how you avid it) and you help yourself by getting something to run or at least understanding how to cause it not to barf.

Start trimming things out and then try to isolate the cause.